How did Euclid's proof of the isosceles triangle theorem (*pons asinorum*) differ from the High School geometry proof?
Consider the first theorem proved in a High School geometry class.
Theorem. The opposite angles of an isosceles triangle are congruent.
Proof.

Construct an angle bisector through the vertex of the triangle
By S-A-S, the two triangles are congruent
Therefore the corresponding parts of the triangles are congruent. Q.E.D.

But Euclid used a proof for the isosceles triangle theorem that differed from the presented, and apparently it was much more complex than the presented. So complex, in fact, that it was used as a way of separating the men students from the asses. Which is why he called it pons asinorum.
Therefore, that raises the question: what was it?

The pons asinorum Wikipedia plot summary gives a summary of Euclid's proof. I have Elements at home; if I remember, I'll check in the evening.

You can search up Euclid's Elements online. For example: https://aleph0.clarku.edu/~djoyce/java/elements/bookI/propI5.html

(corrected comment) Incidentally, no line need be constructed. If in $\triangle ABC$ we have $AB = AC$, we merely observe that in addition, $BC = CB$ and $AC = AB$, so $\triangle ABC \cong \triangle ACB$, so $\angle ABC \cong \triangle ACB$. (This proof due to Pappus.)

Euclid spoke Greek, not Latin, so he couldn't have called it "pons asinorum".  Apparently the name "pons asinorum" dates from the Middle Ages. See e.g. Earliest  Known Uses of Some of the Words of Mathematics (P)

The dedicated History of Science and Mathematics SE may be a better place for this question.

@RobertIsrael https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AncientGrome

Why not median to the base the simplest?

@Moti You don't know if constructing the median will result in two triangles as a given. That's a lemma that the prover will have to prove

If you know where to have the bisector you also know where to have the median. And than prove by s,s,s

@Moti Given an isosceles triangle △ABC with vertex A, it is not possible to know beforehand that constructing a median line m of \overline{BC} will necessarily pass through the vertex A resulting in two triangles. For all you know, at this point in time, it is logically possible that m will miss the vertex, resulting in a trapezoid and a smaller triangle.

How you know which bisector to use?

@Moti, Given an angle there is one unique bisector through that point. I think this is an axiom.

If the angel is given than the base is known!

@Moti Perhaps an angel, but maybe not an angle. :)
